# Quotient of dot products

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec a, \vec b, \vec x \in \mathbb R^n$. Say we have the quotient:
$$ q = \frac{\vec a\cdot\vec x}{\vec b\cdot\vec x} $$
Can we simplify this any further?

I am hopefully looking for an answer in the form $q = \vec c\cdot\vec x,\;\vec c\in\mathbb R^n$ where $\vec c$ is a function of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, but I realize this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done, provided $x\neq 0$.  We have $q=c\cdot x$, where $$c=\frac{a\cdot x}{(b\cdot x)(x\cdot x)}x$$

To my eye this isn't any simpler, but chacun a son gout.

Comment: Hmm... Not really what I was looking for, but thank you! I have edited the last part of my original question to show why.